# Can you Open/Save a Workbook with JExcel to an indefinite Path?

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I am using JExcel to write to Excel Worksheets with my Java Application. When creating or reading from a file I have only been able to do so using a definite path:

Workbook samWB = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/eclipse/samples.xls"));
            Sheet samWS = samWB.getSheet(0);

However, I need to be able to take my application and put it in different locations on a server and have the data files I will be reading from and writing to be in a child folder of the current applications location. Something like this:

Workbook resWB = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("/data/residual.xls"));
                Sheet resWS = resWB.getSheet(0);

Where the folder "data" is inside the folder the application is running from. I have tried a couple different ways and tried searching through the JExcel Programmers guide, but I keep getting errors and all the examples in the Guide use a path "C:/...".

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Not sure that this is a JExcel issue, seems like just an issue figuring out how to find a file with the java File class.  In your example above, remove the first slash - a leading slash tells the class to find 'data' in the root directory.

Comment: I would define a temp folder for your application and use it to save/open/do anything with your files. Maybe you can have 2 folders depending on the OS you are. Another way out can be using the application folder as your main folder and use a temporary folder inside for the file management.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well, I keep getting the error "(The system cannot find the path specified)". 

Is it possible, that this is only an error because I am running the application right now through Eclipse, and it is not actually compiled yet?

Comment: by the way is a desktop, web or mobile application?

Answer (score 0):

I made a console application to test your indefinite relavite path problem. This is the structure of my project:

```
MyProject
+  src
   +  edu.home
      + Main.java
+  tmpFiles
```

In Main.java class, I have this simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("tempFiles/newFile.txt");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When you run the program, the structure for tmpFiles folder is:

```
tmpFiles
+ newFile.txt
```

So, you can create a folder to manage your files in your application. These files can be the Excel files, dat files, etc, and the path will be relative to the location of the application. From the Eclipse IDE I'm working right now, the base path was C:\Workspace, so the file was created here:

```
C:\Workspace\MyProject\tmpFiles
```

When I've moved the project to D:\Java\test\anotherWorkspace, the file was created here:

```
D:\Java\test\anotherWorkspace\MyProject\tmpFiles
```